# Rails does includes really improve queries ? (with bullet)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

```
# Models
class Cinema < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :showtimes
  has_many :movies,         -> { distinct }, through: :showtimes
end

class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :showtimes
  has_many :cinemas,         -> { distinct }, through: :showtimes
end

class Showtime < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cinema
  belongs_to :movie
end

# Controller
class V1::MoviesController < ApplicationController
  movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  render json: MovieSerializer.new(movie, include: [..., :cinemas, :'cinemas.showtimes']).serialized_json
end

# Serializers
class MovieSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  # Relations
  ...
  has_many :cinemas, serializer: CinemaItemSerializer do |object|
    object.cinemas.by_country('FR') #.includes(:showtimes)
  end
end

class CinemaItemSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  # Relations
  has_many :showtimes
end
```

I use the `bullet` gem to trigger some n+1 queries and `fast_json_api` to serialize my objects.

When I don't use `includes(:showtimes)` I have this response time
[image]

If I do use the `includes` I have this response time
[image]

As you see, when I don't use the `includes` my query is slower but the total response time is way faster.

So which one I should use?

Comment: If you are iterating through the showtimes without using `.includes` you will get a n+1 query issue which will be much slower. Which is why bullet warns you - it has nothing to do with the performance of that particular query. If you wan't to know why the query with includes is slower than use `.includes(:showtimes).explain` to check the query plan.

Comment: @max I understand why the query is faster with the includes. But I don’t understand why the total response time is slower

Comment: @Guillaume please add how its being used. Its impossible for us to speculate on why you code slowed down when using include without the code

Comment: @baseballlover723 I just edited my question